# SQLite correct query

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

Let's say i have 2 tables

regs(crc,date,sex)
payments(uid, date, money)

regs has a date of user registration and payments have a date of all user transactions.

1. I need to make an SQL query that returns average payments(money) spent by a user within first  30 days after registration regs(date) for male or female regs(sex).
2. A query that returns the same as above but with a user that has made at least one transaction within first 30 days after registration.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with two levels of aggregation:

```
select 
    sex,
    avg(sum_money) avg_sum_money
from (
    select 
        r.crc,
        r.sex,
        coalesce(sum(p.money), 0) sum_money
    from regs r
    left join payments p 
        on p.uid = r.crc
        and p.date <= date(r.date, '+30 day')
    group by r.crc, r.sex
) t
group by sex
```

The inner query joins the registration table with payments that occured within 30 days after the registration date of the user, aggregates by user and computes the sum of payment per user for that period. Then the outer query aggregates by gender, and computes the average of the total payments. You can run the inner query independently to see what it returns and get a better understanding of what is going on.

This will give you the average amount spent during the first 30 days of subscription, for male and female users.

If you want to ignore users that did not make a transaction within their fist 30 days of subscription, you can just turn `left join payments p` to `inner join payments p`

Comment: @Andrew76868: yes, this query is for sqlite.

Comment: @Andrew76868: I just fixed a typo (missing comma after `select r.crc`).

Comment: GMB, thank you a lot! You've really helped me. Can you please tell what type of query is it and what should i read in order to better understand them ?

Comment: Welcome @Andrew76868! This is a query with two levels of aggregation: fist per user, then per gender. I edited my answer to add more explanation.

Comment: and how can i explain that in order to ignore users that didn't make transactions i should only change Join type?